# kernel of the mod $2$ Bockstein on the first cohomology group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cohomology, homology, steenrod-algebra

Let $M$ be a path-connected finite $CW$-complex.  Suppose the first integral homology group is $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z})= \mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus r}\oplus A$ where $r\geq 1$ and $A$ is a finite abelian group of odd order. Does $M$ necessarily satisfy the property

(1)

For any nonzero element $x\in H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$, $x^2\neq 0$?

---

My attempt: I notice that for any nonzero element $x\in H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)$, $x^2=Sq^1 x=\beta x$ where $\beta$ is the Bockstein homomorphism associated with the coefficient sequence $$
0\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to 0.$$
I want to use these formulas and prove
$$
 \text{Ker} \beta=0.
$$
By the universal coefficient theorem,
$$
H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_4)=Hom(H_1(M;\mathbb{Z});\mathbb{Z}_4) 
=Hom(\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus r};\mathbb{Z}_4) 
=\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus r},$$

$$
H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)=Hom(H_1(M;\mathbb{Z});\mathbb{Z}_2) 
=Hom(\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus r};\mathbb{Z}_2) 
=\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus r}.$$
By the construction of Bockstein homomorphism, we have an exact sequence
$$
H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_4)\overset{f}{\longrightarrow} H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)\overset{\beta}{\longrightarrow }H^2(M;\mathbb{Z}_2).$$

**Question:** Why $\text{Ker}\beta=0$, which is equivalent to say that the image of $f$ is zero?

Comment: Did you try universal coefficients? Everything's in $H_1(X)$: $x^2=0$ iff $x$ lifts to $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}/4)$. Hence, in your example, everything is in the parity of $n$.

Comment: Try using $Sq^1 = \rho\circ\beta$ where $\beta$ is the Bockstein associated to $0\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2\to 0$ and $\rho$ is reduction mod 2.

Comment: If $M$ has only finitely many 1-cells, (1) holds iff $H_1(M)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2)^ r\oplus A$ for some $r \ge 0$ and $A$ a finite abelian group of odd order.

Comment: @tj_ Thanks, Professor! I do not know how to prove your statement. Could you explain more?

Comment: Hint: the universal coefficient theorem is natural with respect to the coefficients.

Comment: @R.S.: The argument is in essential in Alex's comments. I suggest he posts them as an answer. BTW: I much more liked the original formulation of the question.

Comment: @tj_ Thanks, Professor. I already get the proof :)